# angularjs controller not updating page content

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm doing an simple app-ToDoList with login page.the second page have a controller that update dynamically the content of my ToDoList, unfortunately when I launch my application the controller not update the page...there someone that could advice me what's wrong? maybe I'm missing something..
here the application with the code : 
http://plnkr.co/edit/IIYlc1RbEeW8mn9L6YVL?p=preview

**This is the page where load the contents.**

```
<html ng-app="toDoApp" ng-controller="toDoController">
  <head>
    <title>Tasks App</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.28/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.28//angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="ToDocontroller.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>My To-do List</h1>
    <h2>Tasks</h2>
      <table>
        <tr><td>
          <h3>Active ({{ tasks.length }})</h3>
            <span ng-hide="tasks.length">You have no active tasks!</span>
            <div ng-repeat="task in tasks">
              <input type="checkbox" ng-click="transferTo($index, tasks, completed)" /> {{ task }}<br />
            </div>
        </td><td>
          <div ng-show="completed.length">
            <h3>Completed ({{ completed.length }})</h3>
              <div ng-repeat="task in completed">
                <input type="checkbox" ng-click="transferTo($index, completed, tasks)" checked /> <span class="complete">{{ task }}</span><br />
              </div>
          </div>
        </td></tr>
      </table>
    <h2>Add a Task</h2>
      <form ng-submit="addTask()">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Description" ng-model="newTaskName" />
        <input type="submit" value="Add" />
      </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Here  my controller**

```
    angular.module('toDoApp', []) 
            .controller('toDoController', ['$scope', function($scope) { alert('1');
              $scope.tasks = ['Do the laundry'];
              $scope.completed = [];alert('1');
              $scope.newTaskName = '';
              alert('2');
              $scope.addTask = function() {
                var name = $scope.newTaskName;
                if (name && $scope.tasks.indexOf(name) == -1
                         && $scope.completed.indexOf(name)) {
                  $scope.tasks.push(name);
                  $scope.newTaskName = '';
                }
              };
              $scope.transferTo = function(index, start, end) {
                end.push(start[index]);
                start.splice(index, 1);
              }
            }]);
```

tnx in advance

Comment: none of this code is in the controller in your plunker; also, you shouldn't include a plunker with a username / password screen that has nothing to do with your problem and make people figure out how to log in and get to the page you are trying to fix.

Comment: ok, I lied slightly, you have `toDoController` defined twice in your app, once in the app.js and once in `ToDoController.js`.  It seems like you have some confusion over angular routes and partials;  your partial is part of the existing app, and shouldn't have `ng-app` defined inside itself, and it shouldn't have `ng-controller`, since the controller is already supplied by the route itself.

Comment: what?the problem is inherent in what i've postet....if you doing a login you will see that the controller is not update...here i've posted only the part that not working...

Comment: right, the login isn't essential to the problem, so you shouldn't make people have to figure it out in order to diagnose your issue.  And your problem isn't even with the code that is pasted here; you have a half a dozen things wrong with the plunker, I'm just now starting to unravel what you are trying to do.

Comment: you have `ng-route` set up but have no `ng-view` in your HTML, which means your router isn't doing anything, and then you have `ng-template` which is loading a template that has a second angular app inside it, which will never work.  basically, neither of the two `toDoController` instances you tried to load will ever actually be loaded.

Comment: you should spend some time studying how `ng-route` works, and abandon the idea of using `ng-template`.

Comment: see updated plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/C1ubxufRQHN4rfGooxeF?p=preview

Comment: I'll try to learn from my mistake. thank you very much.

Comment: Okay mark it as helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So many mistakes. This is just sample. You should use $route (ng-view or ui-view) for route navigation.. I was updated plnkr.
http://embed.plnkr.co/C1ubxufRQHN4rfGooxeF/

Comment: these changes work, but leave the `ng-route` code isolated and not completely functional.  in general, it's not a good idea to use `ng-include` to try to do routing.

Comment: yeah this is just example only.